Как сделать мультирядный слайдер, при этом чтобы слайды были разной длины? Использую swiper.js
В документации по swiper есть slidesPerView: 'auto' для того чтобы слайды были разной длины, а для мультирядности есть grid: { fill: 'row', rows: 2,}. Но в чем загвоздка, эти свойства не работают коректно вместе. Это предупреждение есть и в документации по swiper:

slidesPerView: 'auto' is currently not compatible with multirow mode, when grid.rows > 1

Если просто слайдам задавать width: auto !important; то опять же ломается слайдер и не хочет работать вместе со свойством у swiper.js grid: 'row', больше одного ряда. Пробовал так же объеденить несколько слайдеров сделав чтобы перелистывая один слайдер перелистывались остальные. И это бы могло сработать если бы на всех разрешениях было бы два ряда слайдов, но по  дизайну макета на мобилах 4 ряда, а планшет и десктоп 2 ряда.
Пробовал по такому примеру: объединеные слайдеры
А так это выглядит на макете:
Слайдер на больших экранах:

Слайдер на мобильных:


Мне кажется нужно делать 2 слайдера и настроить одновременное прокручивание на 1 слайд при нажатии на стрелку. Точно знаю там можно зависимыми их делать друг с другом

Такой вариант попробовал, и это можно сделать. Но получается что на больших экранах два ряда, а на мобиле уже 4. Итого это уже 4 слайдера. Даже и 4 можно было бы, но управлять контентом будет невозможно. На больших экранах придется скрывать два слайдера(3й и 4й ряды), а соответственно и контент будет скрываться с этими слайдерами.
